# How to show menu in children page`s all children pages drupal

Tags: drupal, drupal-8

This is a my code. I show menu in page and children pages. The question is, how to show this menu in children's all children pages?

```
/**
* Implements hook_preprocess_page().
*/
function agnian_material_admin_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
// @todo: add an if statement to add below data only for "page__admin__content" page.
$variables['node_types'] = node_type_get_names();
```

/**
* Render "admin/structure" page's menu in it's all subpages.
*/

```
// get current page path
$path = \Drupal::request()->getPathInfo();
if(strpos($path, '/admin/structure') !== false) {
$tree = \Drupal::menuTree();
$params = $tree->getCurrentRouteMenuTreeParameters('admin');
$admin_menu = $tree->load('admin', $params);
$admin_structure_menu = array_key_exists('system.admin_structure', $admin_menu['system.admin']->subtree) ? $admin_menu['system.admin']->subtree['system.admin_structure'] : null;
if($admin_structure_menu) {
$subtree = $tree->build($admin_structure_menu->subtree);
```

/* this part is only for syncing menu items positions between "admin/structure" page and it's child pages */

```
$old_items = $subtree['#items'];
$tmp = $subtree['#items'] = array();
foreach($old_items as $key => $value) $tmp[$key] = $value['title'];
asort($tmp);
foreach($tmp as $key => $value) $subtree['#items'][$key] = $old_items[$key];
```

/* end of sync */

```
$variables['admin_menu'] = $subtree;
}
}
```

/** End Of Render "admin/structure" page's menu in it's all subpages. */
}

Comment: i dont get it , if u associate the pages and subpages to a menu , using the back office , the menu will then be displayed in all theses pages

Comment: other option create an menu in the back office, display the menu block and on visiblity parameters choose the page you want it to appear

Comment: Thank you, for your replay. I do not understand what is back office?   With this cod menu is shown only in first child, for example my page is x, menu shown in x and it`s child x1 , and not shown in x1`s child x2  ( x > x1> x2 ). MY problem is to show is menu in x2 and x3 pages.

Comment: do u need  complex programatic solution ? have u tried using the possiblity offered by the back office ( /admin)

Comment: I can not use back office , I need only code solutoin

Comment: am i not right or your code is showing the menu only on page /admin/structure ? i guess u need to replace if(strpos($path, '/admin/structure') !== false)  with a regular expression to get all /admin/structure/*

Comment: My code is showing the menu on /admin/structure and /admin/structure/child. I want to show it in   /admin/structure/child/child/child

Answer (score 0):

try replacing

```
 if(strpos($path, '/admin/structure') !== false) {
```

with

```
 if(preg_match("/admin/structure/[^/]+/[^/]+", $path)!== false) {
```

[^/]+ meaning "One or more characters except slashes".

or whatever after structure should be

```
     if(  preg_match("/admin/structure(.*)", $path)!== false) {
```

Comment: Dear, Matoeil. Thank you for your time and reply. I replaced it, but it does not work and even menu doest not shown in parent page ( I do not know what to do (